# .net synthesizer

Tags: c#, .net, audio, vst, synthesis

I'm looking for a synthesizer that I can integrate with my .NET application. Is there any .NET synthesizers available out there? Is there a way of integrating VST-plugins into your .NET application?

I want to create sounds based on MIDI-input, preferably sounds that are more appealing than sine/square/saw waves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try http://vstnet.codeplex.com/ What is not clear is if you want to write a plugin or host an already created one (or maybe both).

Comment: Hosting, if it enables me to interface with the plugin through .net.

Comment: Both tasks can be done with vstnet. Take a look, you'll love it:)

Comment: Yes, you can make a VST Host in .NET with VST.NET. But I advise you to really get to grips with the interaction between VST Host and Plugin before actually attempting to write one. The tasks a Host must/should fulfill can be pretty complex and VST.NET does nothing to make those tasks any easier. It just provides you (a managed host) with a way to load and communicate with unmanaged (C++) or managed (.NET) plugins. Leave your questions at the codeplex site's discussion list, there are several developers there that already have build a managed host. Good luck and have fun!